# How to navigate through Next.js SSR pages like in SPA?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

**Next.js, pages router, 13v.**

This task needs to be done so that when you first access the page, **getServerSideProps** is triggered and the page is rendered on the server, and if you are already moving from one page to another, it is on the site that the pages open instantly, like in SPA, without rendering on the server.

prop `<Link href="..." shallow>` only works if you go to the same page, that is, if you go `/provider/[id]`*(/provider/424)* to another `/provider/[id]`*(/ provider/723)* then SSR will not trigger. But if you switch to a completely different route, it will trigger.

I also found answers on the Internet that you just need to use **next/link** and it works automatically, I tried it, unfortunately it doesn’t work, maybe you need to specify some props other than shallow?

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, you can use `next/link` along with `getServerSideProps`,  if you're using `next/link`, you'll want to ensure that you're also using `next/router`, below is the code to setup it:

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const IndexPage = ({ data }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    router.prefetch('/other-page'); // Prefetch other pages if needed
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Index Page</h1>
      <ul>
        {data.map(item => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            <Link href={`/provider/${item.id}`} passHref>
              <a>{item.name}</a>
            </Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // Fetch data from server
  const data = await fetchData(); // Implement fetchData function

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  };
}

export default IndexPage;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just checked this method, but unfortunately it doesn’t work. It is also not suitable because you need to prefetch all the links that are on each page)

Comment: One option could be to use a combination of client-side and server-side rendering with the help of Next.js's useEffect hook and conditional fetching.